# powershell measure info. Count lines of code

Tags: powershell, cat, measure

I have a "projects" folder and within that folder, I have individual solution folders. For example:

- Projects

  - Project 1
  - Project 2
  - Project 3

and so on. Note that a project folder may have multiple sub folders and c# solutions but that does not matter. I only want the lines of code per project folder.

Using Powershell, I want to count the lines of code per project folder so from within my top level Project folder, I typed the following:

```
ls | select name, @{n="LinesOfCode";e={(ls -Path $_.fullname -Recurse -Include *.cs | cat | measure).Lines}} -First 1
```

The lines column return nothing. However, if (just for debugging purposes) I remove the "measure" command and end with the "cat" command as in the following:

```
ls | select name, @{n="LinesOfCode";e={(ls -Path $_.fullname -Recurse -Include *.cs | cat).Length}} -First 1
```

The cat command retuns a value. Why does cat and not measure?

Thanks in advance.

**Update**
So the above issue was resolved thanks to Mathias R. Jessen but now, I measure command returns a value of 1 for all folders.

```
ls | select name, @{n="LinesOfCode";e={(ls -Path $_.fullname -Recurse -Force -Filter *.cs | cat | measure -Line).Count}}
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `measure` (alias for `Measure-Object`), you'll need to reference the `Count` property, it doesn't have a `Lines` property:

```
ls | select name, @{n="LinesOfCode";e={(ls -Path $_.Fullname -Recurse -Include *.cs |cat |measure).Count}} -First 1
```

Comment: It's too early for this. Thanks @Mathias. Good catch!